# Can a Patronus take the form of any animal?

Tags: harry-potter, spells

As far as I can recall, all of the Patronuses that are seen in the books (and movies) are small- to medium-sized mammals and a few are birds.  I could've missed some, but I don't think there are any lizards, fish, or insects.

Does a Patronus *have* to take the form of a moderate-sized bird or mammal?  Dumbledore and Tonks both have magical creatures as their Patronuses, so clearly that's a possibility, but would a unicorn Patronus be possible?  What about a T-Rex (that would be *my* choice, if I could pick)?  Or, if Patronuses are limited to warm-blooded animals, could someone have an elephant Patronus?

Comment: I remember someone having an otter Patronus that swims around them. This is a mammal, but since it "swims" through the air I imagine it's possible for there to be fish or other ocean-dwelling creatures - since they don't have to walk on legs to move.

Comment: I think, its decided by one's imagination...

Comment: T Rex was may have been warm-blooded

Comment: How about a human Patronus? I imagine if Gilderoy Lockhart had a Patronus, it would be himself.

Comment: See also http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/15348/4918

Comment: Tonks had a wolf patronus, not a werewolf.

Comment: @trysis Classic. But that's then insulting animals and complimenting him isn't it? He has enough compliments and animals don't get enough respect as it is!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The obvious counterexample is that Harry's is a stag, not a small animal by any means. Ginny's horse would also not be considered small.  However there are presumably size limits - Andros the Invincible is notable for creating a giant-sized Patronus, the only person on record as doing so.  Given the size and magicality is not an issue, unicorn Patronuses should be possible and elephants potentially.

Comment: Not small, no, but I was calibrating the large end of the scale with elephant and T-Rex.

Comment: What was Andros's Patronus?

Comment: It wasn't specified.

Comment: How large are Giants in Harry Potter again?  Larger than an elephant?  How about a T-Rex?  In fact, what size are T-Rexes believed to be [these days](http://xkcd.com/1104/)?

Comment: We've got new information since you have posted this answer.  An unusually large sized patronus is produced in the climax of the *My Little Pony: Equestria Girls: Rainbow Rocks* film.  It's hard to tell the exact size, but it may be larger than a giant.

Comment: James's Patronus was also a stag - as was his Animagus form. Wasn't it?

Comment: @Pryftan Yes, James and Harry had the same Patronus.

Comment: @Bellatrix I thought so. But I think I was totally knackered when I wrote that comment because I was mixing it up with a linked question and at first wrote a comment not about the Patronus but Animagus. I believe I ended up deleting that comment but what purpose the comment above was I haven't a clue: a stag is already cited so I guess the only value to the comment is it's yet another instance of a larger creature. Edit: Probably mixed the two also because James's Animagus form was a stag as was his Patronus.

Answer (score 13):

Since this question and its answers are a bit old, I want to add some canon info from new material unveiled on Pottermore.

> "No reliable system for predicting the form of an individual's Patronus has ever been found, although the great eighteenth-century researcher of Charms, Professor Catullus Spangle, set forth certain principles that are widely accepted as true.
>
> The Patronus, asserted Spangle, **represents that which is hidden, unknown but necessary within the personality**... []... Here, says Spangle, is the explanation for the appearance of Patronuses in forms that their casters might not expect, for which they have never felt a particular affinity, or (in rare cases) **[a form that the caster may not] even recognise**....
>
> It is usual, but not inevitable, for a Patronus to take the form of an animal commonly found in the caster's native country. Given their long affinity with humans it is perhaps unsurprising that among the **most common Patronuses** (although it must be remembered that any corporeal Patronus is highly unusual) are dogs, cats and **horses**. ...
>
> **Extinct Patronuses are very rare but not unknown**. Strangely, given their long connection with wizardkind, owl Patronuses are unusual. **Most uncommon of all possibly Patronuses are magical creatures such as *dragons*, *Thestrals* and phoenixes.** ... While a rare and magical Patronus undoubtedly reflects an unusual personality, it does not follow that it is more powerful, or will enjoy greater success at defending its caster."

If a **thestral** is possible and a **horse** is common, the similarly size unicorn should not be an issue *because* of size, and if both ***Dragons*** and **extinct animals** in general are possible, a T-Rex should not be out of the question either.

Note, however, that according to Spangles, being able to *choose* your Patronus is rare, and possibly a sign of obsession or eccentricity, or a sign that they "may not be able to hide their essential self in common life, who may, indeed, parade tendencies that others might prefer to conceal."

Answer (score 8):

There was once a witch in the lore of J. K. Rowling's "Book of Spells" who had a ladybird patronus, so I assume that insects are allowed, too.

Answer (score 3):

[Hedley Fleetwood](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Hedley_Fleetwood) was known to have had a wooly mammoth for a patronus, which is much bigger than an elephant

Answer (score 1):

### Most, but not all

As shown through [JK Rowling's writings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/120951/what-different-animal-forms-have-patronuses-taken-in-harry-potter-canon/120952#120952) and through [the Pottermore quiz](https://www.reddit.com/r/harrypotter/comments/53yufn/pottermore_patronus_test_all_possible_questions/), there are about 150 different known Patronus types. This shows a wide variety in what animals Patronuses can form.

But there are some types of animals which can't be Patronuses.
Rowling said [on twitter](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/778998962367918084):

> I've been asked to make it clear that Harambe is not a Patronus you can actually get on pottermore. The previous RT is a joke. As you were.