# How did Scorpius' Patronus take the form of Albus?

Tags: harry-potter, the-cursed-child

In *Harry Potter and the Cursed Child*, Scorpius's Patronus takes the form of his best friend, Albus, if I recall correctly. Isn't a Patronus supposed to take a form of an animal or creature? So, how did his take the form of Albus?

Comment: wait *what?* I don't remember this at all, and I can't find anything that confirms this? are you sure that his Patronus was Albus?

Comment: It's from the Cursed Child.

Comment: I don't believe he even had a Patronus?

Comment: Are you sure this is the case? Did you maybe read some fan fiction or fan theory based on *The Cursed Child*? I don't recall this at all, and I can't find it on the wiki.

Comment: Given that Scorpius doesn't cast a Patronus in Cursed Child, I'm at a loss what you're trying to ask.

Comment: I don’t think a false premise makes a question unclear.

Comment: Are you perhaps confusing this with the fan-fiction [*Harry Potter and the Methods of Rationality*](http://www.hpmor.com/)? There is a human Patronus in that...

Comment: @Skooba - Oh dear, Harry's?

Answer (score 5):

I can't say I know much about *Cursed Child*, but a quick search for the word "patronus" in a PDF of *Cursed Child* turns up six results (seven if you add "patronum"), none of which even mention Scorpius casting one let alone that it took the form of Albus. So I don't think this would present a conflict with the assumption that a patronus must be an animal (which we already have [a question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/125754/must-a-physical-patronus-charm-take-the-form-of-an-animal) about).