# Why are the Harry Potter crests normal (Muggle) animals?

Tags: harry-potter

In a world that is full of fantastic beasts known to the Wizarding community why are the crests for the houses at Hogwarts normal or Muggle animals (snake, lion, badger, eagle)? Also all the animals that the students and teachers conjure when using the Patronus charm e.g.. Harry’s stag, Hermione’s Otter and Luna’s Hare. Dumbledore has a Phoenix and rightly so, but that’s the only magical creature in the lot.

Was this an oversight, a missed opportunity, a way to simplify the world or just merely a way to make us Muggles identify more strongly with the animals we are familiar with?

Also Animagus' can so far as I know only transform to non magical creatures...

Comment: Possibly because magical creatures are more rare

Comment: It would just appear to be a matter of choice. For what it's worth, the US school uses magical creatures for it house crests. https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/ilvermorny

Comment: Oh that’s great about the American school! That’s what I would have expected from Hogwarts. Even though the animals they have chosen do reflect the traits of the houses and of course Slitherin could be nothing other than a snake (Basilisk would have been a good choice)

Comment: Related to your second and third points: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15220/can-a-patronus-take-the-form-of-any-animal https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53739/can-an-animagus-take-the-form-of-any-animal?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: It is claimed that the question already has an answer elsewhere, but that question doesn't address why the animals are not magical.